# Using PreferenceFragment as BottomSheet (Dialog)

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, preferencefragment

How can I use a PreferenceFragment as BottomSheet(Dialog) ? Obviously I can't derive from PreferenceFragment and BottomSheetDialogFragment at once. Also I'd like the user to still be able to click on other items in the original fragment. So not really a dialog.

I'm using kotlin and the androidx support libraries, if you want to take that into account.

Comment: You can have that type of behaviour, like wrap a FragmentContainerView in your BottomSheet and inflate the SettingsFragment there which extends the PreferenceFragmentCompat.

Comment: An example would be nice to at least know you for example inflate the settings fragment.